# Node JS : socket.io - handling multiple connection

Tags: node.js

I am a newbie in using socket.io in Node JS - however I have coded a client (web page) / server program to render some statistics data at client side.
The requirement is like – to render a box statistics (out of many). Since the user can open multiple browser windows - we have a scenario where one box data can be requested by many times:

http://www.tool.com?boxname=box1

As such I want to achieve spawning one job for multiple requests for same box. Below is the logic I have implemented to meet the requirement:

Client Side:

1. Establishes a connection to server creating a data channel:

   socket.on(boxname.toLowerCase(), function (data){
   }

So whenever there is a data in boxname event I receive, parse the data and render it.

Server Side

1. First call an expect script to copy a script to run within an infinite loop on a box.
2. On successful copying of the script in the box - invoke another expect script to start its execution:

   exports.ServiceMonitor = function(boxName, res) {

Step 1.

I need to copy a script as many times request comes else I would not be able to enter ‘exit’ event of this spawned process where I start the script execution as mentioned below:

```
var child = spawn('./scripts/copyscriptonbox.sh' , [boxName.toLowerCase(), getURL(boxName)]);
```

In the later part of the code I keep adding box names to boxnames variable which is declared global. So on a new boxname request - I search for number of occurrences of boxname in boxnames variable. If the count is 1 or more it would mean to me that a script is already running on that box:

```
        var noofbox = boxnames.split(boxName.toLowerCase()).length - 1;

        child.on('exit', function (code) {
                logger.info('child stream exit: ' + code);
                if(code == 0)
                {
                        boxNames +=  boxName.toLowerCase();
                        logger.info('Box name added: ' + boxNames);
                        res.render('boxpage', {}); //render a web page
                        io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
            logger.info('Connected to box :' + boxName);
            if(noofbox <= 0)            
                           schild = spawn('./scripts/boxmon.sh', [boxName.toLowerCase(), getURL(boxName)]);
                        schild.on('exit', function (code) {
                                logger.info('schild stream exit.');
                         });
                        schild.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
                                logger.info('stderr: ' + data);
                        });
                        schild.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
                              //generate response
                        });
                        socket.on('disconnect',function(){logger.info('Disconnect Killed');ServiceMonitorEnd(boxName.toLowerCase());});
                        });
                }
        });
}
```

The issue is that if in two browser window I access URL : www.tool.com?boxname=box1 - first time I get the log only once (Connected to box : box1) but second time I get the same logs 2 times where as I was expecting it to be one time - I mean as many request comes in after the first one the logs gets printed that many times – if 5 then log gets printed for 1(first time)+2 (second time)+3(third time)+4 (fourth time)+5 (fifth time)? I understand that when ‘connection’ event is called for x times then it enters that many times for each connection.
How can I make the 'connection' event on the socket.io once for each request only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `socket.once` instead of `socket.on`, it is another EventEmitter like .on, that is emitted only once, the first time. Check the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_event_listener). But remember after that any such events will not be received by the client.